# Bind AvalonEdit to XML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xml, avalonedit

I'm using an AvalonEdit control in my WPF project, and I use it with XML syntax highlighting. I am just using it as an XML editor (no need for tree view on the side or anything). What I want is:

1. Bind it to some sort of XML data structure, and get notifications when a node is being removed/updated/deleted.
2. Use an auto-compliation based on an XSD file.

I saw that the new AvalonEdit has an `ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Xml` namepsace, but I couldn't figure out how to use it for my own needs. Any suggestions?

Comment: try using http://xmlautocomplete.codeplex.com/ - will soon support syntax highlighting...

Answer (score 1):

I know how to do the 1st part (I am assuming you can use LINQ (i.e have .NET 3.5 or above), that is simply a question of using some XLINQ and wiring up the 2 events Changed/Changing, as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static XDocument doc; 

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            doc = XDocument.Parse("<books><book>Gone with the wind</book></books>");
            doc.Changed += Doc_Changed;
            doc.Changing += Doc_Changing;

            PrintResults();

            XElement newElement = new XElement("book", "Treasure Island");

            doc.Elements().First().Add(newElement);
            newElement.Remove(); //remove this noe from parent
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Doc_Changing(object sender, XObjectChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintChangeResults(e);
        }

        static void Doc_Changed(object sender, XObjectChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintChangeResults(e);
        }

        public static void PrintChangeResults(XObjectChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Change was {0}, Document now has {1} elements", 
                e.ObjectChange, doc.Elements().First().Elements().Count()));
        }

        public static void PrintResults()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Document now has {0} elements", 
                doc.Elements().First().Elements().Count()));
        }
    }
}
```

Which will result in something like the following output

Document now has 1 elements
Change was Add, Document now has 1 elements
Change was Add, Document now has 2 elements
Change was Remove, Document now has 2 elements
Change was Remove, Document now has 1 elements

So that should get you 1/2 way there (providing you can make use of LINQ)